# Azure Active Directory Domain Services DNS Forwarding

Tags: azure, dns, azure-ad-domain-services

Background:

We recently set up Azure Active Directory Domain Services for several Azure Virtual Machines.  The domain name we used is **mycompany.com** and the virtual machines are **machine01** and **machine02**.  We also have several websites  using the same domain such as **www.mycompany.com** or **faq.mycompany.com**.

The issue:

There are several scheduled tasks running on these virtual machines which screen scrape the websites with the same domain name.  The scheduled tasks running locally are unable to resolve dns for something like **www.mycompany.com** or **faq.mycompany.com**.

```
C:\windows\system32>ping www.mycompany.com
Ping request could not find host www.mycompany.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

The dns names resolve just fine outside of the virtual machines.  Dns names such as **machine01.mycompany.com** or **machine02.mycompany.com** also resolve correctly on the virtual machine:

```
C:\windows\system32>ping machine01.mycompany.com    
Pinging machine01.mycompany.com [10.0.3.9] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.3.9: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

I am thinking Active Directory is seeing the **mycompany.com** and only resolves it internally and does not try to resolve a name such as **faq.mycompany.com** beyond the domain server.  I believe I could normally add a forwarder to Active Directory DNS to solve this issue.  But how do I get dns to forward with Azure Active Directory Domain Services?

**** EDIT 2019-02-07 ****

I did find how to administer the Azure AD Domain Services domain for a domain connected virtual machine.  This article shows how to add the DNS manager: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-administer-dns

But we should have configured the Azure Active Directory Domain Services domain as something like **corp.mycompany.com** instead of just **mycompany.com**.

So the solutions we have are:

- Add an alias into dns
- Edit the local hosts file
- Delegate a sub-domain

Adding an alias into DNS worked for us and is the solution we are going to go with.

Answer (score 1):

While I have no direct answer to your question, you can work around by populating hosts files on the nodes to "skip" dns resolution

Comment: Yes, a workaround is to edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts but I was really hoping to solve this permanently.

Comment: I'm not saying there isnt a fix, but I suggest you implement this one while you wait for the answer, because there might not be an answer ;)